# How to automatically expose all .rs files in a directory in a module?

Tags: rust

I have module files generated from protobuf definitions. There are a lot of files and they will grow with time. This is the structure:

```
proto_rust/src/lib.rs
proto_rust/src/protos/{lots of auto generated .rs files}
proto_rust/src/protos/mod.rs
```

Since there are lots of files in `proto_rust/src/protos/`, it does not make sense for me to manually put them in `mod.rs`. Is there a way to expose all them to `lib.rs`? Something like `pub mod *`.

Answer (score 2):

Use dtolnay's [automod](https://crates.io/crates/automod) crate.

> ```rust
> automod::dir!("path/to/directory");
> ```
>
> This macro expands to one or more mod items, one for each source file
> in the specified directory.
>
> The path is given relative to the directory containing Cargo.toml.