# How can I import a nested module without creating a mod.rs?

Tags: rust, module

I'm creating a binary project that will be a web application. I'd like to have `src/main.rs` be the startup code, with various handlers for routes and pages under `src/handlers/get_foo.rs` or `src/handlers/post_quux.rs`, etc.

As I understand Rust's module system, in order to do this, I have to also create `src/handlers/mod.rs` wherein I include `mod get_foo;` and also `pub use get_foo::get_foo_handler;`.

Then, from `src/main.rs` I have to `mod handlers;` and access my handler as `handlers::get_foo_handler` when I boot up the application.

Is there a way to include each of the nested modules under `src/handlers/*.rs` without having boilerplate `mod.rs` to include the child modules and re-export the handlers?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How to automatically expose all .rs files in a directory in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64111483/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, that does solve my issue. I appreciate the link.